# What happens with socket's client scope on 'disconnect' event (server side)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, socket.io

So What happens with socket's client scope on `'disconnect'` event?

I'm trying to avoid bad racing conditions and logic flaws in my node.js + mongoose + socket.io app.

What do I mean by scope is:

```
io.on('connection', function (client) { 
///CLIENT SCOPE///
//define private vars, store and operate client's session info//
//recieving and sending client's socket signals//
}
```

Some background:
Let's say, for example, I implement some  function that operates db by finding `room` and writing `user` to this `room`.

BUT, in the moment when the `room` (to be written in) found, but user yet not written in - he disconnects. On disconnect event i must pull him out of his last room in db, but i can not, it's not saved in db for this moment yet.
The only way I see is to assign a `bool` value on `'disconnect'` event against which i can check before saving guy in to the `room` and in the case of `true` don't save him at all.

What i'm confused with - would this `bool` survive a disconnect event, as it saved in client's scope.

*What happens with the scope*? is it completely wiped out on disconnect? or it's wiped out only when everything that relys on this scope is finished?

I'm using `'forceNew': true`  to force `socket.connect();` to socket immedietly if something goes wrong (hypothetically) and `socket error` fired without user really leaving the site.
If user reconnects through this 'old' socket is he getting back his scope on server, or this socket's previous scope has been wiped out on his disconnection or wiped out on reconnection by on `'connection'` event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `client` closure will remain alive as long as there is code running that uses that closure so you generally don't have to worry about that issue.  A closure is essentially an object in Javascript and it will only be garbage collected when there is no active code that has a reference to anything inside the closure.

As for your concurrency issue with a socket being disconnected while you are writing to the DB, you are correct to recognize that this is an issue to be careful with.  Exactly what you need to do about it depends a bit on how your database behaves.  Because node.js runs single threaded, your node.js code writing to the database will run to completion before any disconnect event gets processed.  This doesn't mean that the database write will have completed before the disconnect event starts processing, but it does mean that it will have already been sent to the database.  So, if your database processes multiple requests in the order it receives them, then it will likely just do the right thing and you won't have any extra code to worry about.

If your database could actually process the delete before the write finishes (which seems unlikely), then you'd have to code up some protection for that.  The simplest concept there is to implement a database queue on all database operations for a given user.  I'd probably create an object with common DB methods on it to implement this queue and create a separate object in each `client` closure so they were local to a given user.  When a database operation is in process, this object would have a flag indicating that an operation was in progress.  If another database operation was called while this flag was set, that second operation would go in a queue rather than being sent directly to the database.  Each time a database operation finishes, it checks the queue to see if there is a next operation is waiting to run.  If so, it runs it.

FYI, I have a simple node.js app (running on a Raspberry Pi with temperature sensors) that records temperature data and every so-often it writes that data to disk using async writes.  Because new temperature data could arrive while I'm in the middle of my async writes of the data, I have a similar issue.  I abstracted all operations on the data in an object, implemented a flag that indicates if I'm in the process of writing the data and, if any method calls arrive to modify the data, then those operations go in a queue and they are processed only when the write has finished.

---

As to your last question, the `client` scope you have in the `io.on('connection', ...)` closure is associated only with that particular `connection` event.  If you get another `connection` event and thus this code is triggered to run again, that will create a new and separate closure that has nothing to do with the prior one, even if the `client` object is the same.  Normally, this works out just fine because your code in this function will just set things up again for a new connection.

Comment: So the database is mongoose nad its noSQL Db that works on asynchronous calls, as i understand that means, if i have  db delete call on `disconnect` then it can be fired in the time when i found an item in db but not saved it yet (it works like `founOne('query' function(found) {change-found; found.save(function(err,saved) {done!})})`
And when delete is fired db not yet know that i will  want  to change and save this doc that i've found. It seems like racing condition.
...continued reading your awesome answer.

Comment: And yeah the idea with Q is nice, i just felt that it maybe an overshoot and want to be sure that it's needed, and, honestly just felt lazy about implementing such a thing. And its totally a bad excuse for not doing this already.
Really appreciate such a full answer. thank you.
Btw i got a small follow up question about those reconnections. I'm woried about how can i maintain socket connection errors and server critical errors. If server is down and auto restarted - whic wipes out all the current user's sessions, that means this will kick users out of their rooms, which is...

Comment: pretty unpleasant. So do You have any idea about is there any way to carry clients closure session info in some kind of automated way? I can write those sessions in db to further reconnect users to their rooms and eachother in case of some kind critical failure, but i dont know how can i logically bind just reconnected after error user to his previous session data. Got any guidelines?

Comment: @MaxYari - Anytime you use multiple DB operations as part of one transaction, you have a potential race condition.  You either have to just handle any errors appropriately that may result, build some notion of a transaction to give you the type of integrity you need or make sure the race condition can't occur (this depends on lot of specifics about what can really happen and when in your server and database).